# Bind different ip addresses to scrapy spiders

Tags: python, ip, scrapy

How can I bind different public ip addresses to scrapy spider? And furthermore, is it possible to set rate limit for each source ip (like CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_SOURCE_IP).

From scrapy documentation, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP both seem to work with target domain and target ip.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but requires you to alter the Scrapy core a tiny bit.
Someone else made a change proposal some time ago, but it never made it by the looks of the current source.

With [the information in this change proposal](http://dev.scrapy.org/ticket/153) you should be able to patch it in yourself in a couple of minutes.

Although the change proposal is well over 1,5 years old, the current source of the edited files for that specific proposal are still much alike.